# FileStream.Write blocking for long periods on SSD

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I'm writing ~280MB of data in 2MB blocks to a FileStream.

On one machine, this completes in under 8 seconds. On my machine (with similar spec, SSD etc) I've been trying to debug why it takes over 40 seconds and their are pauses in the progress.

I write the data when its returned from a hardware device, but I've found that sometimes, calling Write on the stream can take ages to return. I'm calling flush between all the writes:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    _stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);        
    stopwatch.Stop(); 
    Console.WriteLine("_stream.Write() " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");             

    _stream.Flush();
```

Output:

```
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
... snip 
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 23233ms    <- not expecting this
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 0ms
... snip 
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 15852ms    <- or this
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
... snip 
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 25ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
_stream.Write() 2ms
```

This is not what I would expect

Comment: Any errors in the event viewer? Seems an hardware problem to me.

Comment: I'm going to have to second MiMo's comment. Sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: A full file system cache easily explains this.  Buy more RAM.

Comment: My dev machine which is having the problems is: i7-3930k @ 4GHz,  16GB of RAM, 120GB Corsair Force 3  SSD, Windows 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually suspect it maybe what you think should be making it fast. The SSD is likely the culprit.

So here is what is weird. SSD like .net have a GC. This is because SSDs unlike HDDs can't delete information in same way it writes information. The smallest unit of write is much smaller than the smallest unit of delete.

For more information search Write Amplification.

The industry knew about this so they developed a feature in SATA called TRIM. However my research shows that there were batches of the Corsair Force 3 that had TRIM disabled in the firmware for some odd reason...

Comment: I couldn't update the firmware on my SSD as it was showing up as a SCSI device on my X79 motherboard. I swapped it from a Marvel 6G SATA port to an Intel 6G SATA port and it then showed as an AHCI device. I then updated the SSD firmware from 1.5 > 5.02 and the long pauses have stopped!

Answer (score 1):

You could always run the Write on an async thread and just callback when the process of writing is complete?